# I2C multibyte transfer

Tags: i2c, atmega

When we want to transfer a single byte we send it as described in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrjlf.png).

When we transfer data in multiburst mode, we send address (of starting register) right after the acknowledge from slave instead of data. Then we send data and register address is automatically increment as shown in [this book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wDu8.png).

My question is that:

How Slave recognize that the byte, right after the first acknowledge, is address or data?

Hint: I used Google a lot but I couldn’t find an answer that would have satisfied me.

Comment: I think you're better off posting this on http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm new to this forum. I don't know much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slave can recognize the fact that the address spans over two bytes by  checking the first address byte for a special bit pattern. A slave address beginning with the bit pattern of `1111 0` indicates a 10 bit address (as opposed to the regular 7 bit addresses) which spans over two bytes on the bus as defined in the [I2C Bus Specification](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf):

> **3.1.11 10-bit addressing**
>
> [...]
>
> The 10-bit slave address is formed from the first two bytes following a START condition
>   (S) or a repeated START condition (Sr).
>   The first seven bits of the first byte are the combination 1111 0XX of which the last two bits
>   (XX) are the two Most-Significant Bits (MSB) of the 10-bit address; the eighth bit of the
>   first byte is the R/W bit that determines the direction of the message.

If the first address byte does not match the special bit pattern, the second byte would have to be treated as data.
So, in your example

```
| START | slave address | R/W | ACK | slave address | ACK | data      | ...
| S     | 1111 000      | 0   | A   | 0000 1111     | A   | 0000 0001 | ...
```

the master is reading multiple data bytes from a slave identified by the 10 bit address `00 0000 1111`.

Comment: what do you mean by span? Further I'm far away from 10-bit address. I'm only talking about 7-bit addressing and 8-bit micro-controller e.g. Atmega32.

Comment: I mean the address continues after the first acknowledge (and it is indeed a 10-bit address then of which 2 bits are located in the first address byte and the remaining 8 bits are placed in byte 2 after the first acknowledge). This has nothing to do with the type of microcontroller you're using, it's just about I2C addressing.